# Why is it that my CGRects are not properly registering when touched?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch

Here is a rather large chunk of code. The comments should be pretty helpful. What I'm trying to do is iterate through an NSArray of CGRects (wrapped in NSValues) and check if the place we're currently touching is inside one of those CGRects.

When I run this code however (notice the NSLog statement in the for loop), all it ever does is say that the current loop value is 0. Furthermore, it does this when I touch places that are nowhere near where the CGRects should be. My comments explain how I created the CGRects. Thanks!

```
#import "GameUI.h"


@implementation GameUI // This is a scene with just 1 layer on it.

+(id) scene
{
 // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
 CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

 // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
 GameUI *layer = [GameUI node];

 // add layer as a child to scene
 [scene addChild: layer];

 // return the scene
 return scene;
}

// initialize your instance here
-(id) init
{
 if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255,255,255,255)] )) {

  // enable touches
  self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

  // unlock touching ingredients to start with
  touchLocked = NO;

  // attach nothing
  attachedSprite = -1;

  winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

  // Build the UI
   // Counter
    CCSprite *counter = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"counter.png" 
              rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
    counter.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:counter]; 

  // Let's hardcode some hitbox bounds.
  // I got these values by using Photoshop's info panel and simply using the rectangular marquee tool.
  // That gave me the origin point and then the two width+height values.
  breadTouchbox = CGRectMake(241, 12, 71, 61);
  onionTouchbox = CGRectMake(166, 11, 63, 53);
  hamTouchbox = CGRectMake(115, 60, 56, 58);
  cheeseTouchbox = CGRectMake(108, 128, 74, 74);
  tomatoTouchbox = CGRectMake(47, 162, 52, 47);
  lettuceTouchbox = CGRectMake(4, 78, 70, 77);
  ketchupTouchbox = CGRectMake(2, 166, 38, 69);
  mayoTouchbox = CGRectMake(6, 242, 31, 75);

  NSValue *breadTouchboxValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:breadTouchbox];
  NSValue *onionTouchboxValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:onionTouchbox];
  NSValue *hamTouchboxValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:hamTouchbox];
  NSValue *cheeseTouchboxValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:cheeseTouchbox];
  NSValue *tomatoTouchboxValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:tomatoTouchbox];
  NSValue *lettuceTouchboxValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:lettuceTouchbox];
  NSValue *ketchupTouchboxValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:ketchupTouchbox];
  NSValue *mayoTouchboxValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:mayoTouchbox];

  // Put them in the array
  touchboxArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:breadTouchboxValue, onionTouchboxValue, hamTouchboxValue, cheeseTouchboxValue, tomatoTouchboxValue, lettuceTouchboxValue, ketchupTouchboxValue, mayoTouchboxValue, nil];

  // Create the sprites we're going to drag around. Spawn them off screen somewhere.
  breadSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"breadslice.png" rect:CGRectMake(0,0,-200,-200)];
  onionSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"onionslices.png" rect:CGRectMake(0,0,-200,-200)];
  hamSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"hamslice.png" rect:CGRectMake(0,0,-200,-200)];
  cheeseSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"cheeseslices.png" rect:CGRectMake(0,0,-200,-200)];
  tomatoSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"tomatoslices.png" rect:CGRectMake(0,0,-200,-200)];
  lettuceSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"lettuceslice.png" rect:CGRectMake(0,0,-200,-200)];
  ketchupSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ketchupsplurge.png" rect:CGRectMake(0,0,-200,-200)];
  mayoSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mayosplurge.png" rect:CGRectMake(0,0,-200,-200)];

  // Make sure you add them to this layer.
  [self addChild:breadSprite];
  [self addChild:onionSprite];
  [self addChild:hamSprite];
  [self addChild:cheeseSprite];
  [self addChild:tomatoSprite];
  [self addChild:lettuceSprite];
  [self addChild:ketchupSprite];
  [self addChild:mayoSprite];

  // Put them in the array
  spriteArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:breadSprite, onionSprite, hamSprite, cheeseSprite, tomatoSprite, lettuceSprite, ketchupSprite, mayoSprite, nil];
 }
 return self;
}

- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 // Set the currently touched location to LOCATION.
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

 // NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location));

 // Check for a touch in any of the touchboxes. If yes, break out of the loop so you preserve arrayCount's value.
 int arrayCount = 0;
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool =  [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 for (int i = 0; i < [touchboxArray count]; i++) {
  CGRect rect = [[touchboxArray objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue];
  if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, location)) {
   NSLog(@"The value of arrayCount is %i", arrayCount);
   break;
  }
 }
 [pool release];

 // Now use that value to find the appropriate sprite and set it up for finger attachment.
 // Remember to lock further touches [DO WE EVEN NEED TOUCHLOCKED? CAN'T SWIPE THROUGH SHIT ANYMORE]
 //attachedSprite = arrayCount;

}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 // Set the currently touched location to LOCATION.
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

 // Make a holder sprite.
 CCSprite *currentIngredient;

 // Check and see if there is a sprite to be attached. If there is, attach it to the touch location.
 if (attachedSprite != -1) {
  currentIngredient = [spriteArray objectAtIndex:attachedSprite];
  currentIngredient.position = location;
 }
}

- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 // Remove any attachment.
 attachedSprite = -1;
    }

-(void)ccTouchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 // Remove any attachment.
 attachedSprite = -1;
}
@end
```

Comment: You never change the value of arrayCount - why wouldn't you expect it to be 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer provided in the comment by @deanWombourne*

The row

`NSLog(@"The value of arrayCount is %i", arrayCount);`

should be

`NSLog(@"The value of arrayCount is %i", i);`